# Do paths in HTML file need to be full path when using Express.static?

Tags: html, node.js, express

I have the following files:

**/public/index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>    
    <title>Planner</title>
    <script src="../codebase/library.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <link href="../codebase/library.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
    <link href="./styles.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="../app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**/server.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const sql = require("mssql")
const app = express();
const port = 4000;

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.use(express.static( __dirname + "/public"));

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${port}...`);
});
```

If I browse to the index.html in my file explorer and open it everything runs fine.

But using the

> app.use(express.static( __dirname + "/public"));

I want to be able to browse to http://localhost:4000 to run the application.

This works the page is loaded, but the CSS and JavaScript links in my HTML file can't be found. The console reports:

> GET http://localhost:4000/codebase/library.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
> (Not Found)
>
> Refused to execute script from
> 'http://localhost:4000/codebase/library.js' because its MIME type
> ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is
> enabled.
>
> Refused to apply style from
> 'http://localhost:4000/codebase/library.css' because its MIME type
> ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME
> checking is enabled.
>
> GET http://localhost:4000/app.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
>
> Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:4000/app.js' because
> its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type
> checking is enabled.

Do I have to use full path for them, or is there something that sorts this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: No. Because your HTML files "are nothing" until they're loaded in a browser, by which point there is no file system, only the web, composed of URLs. Everything you link to in your HTML (`<a`>, `<link>`, etc. etc) is just more URLs, so there is no `../codebase/library.js` URL relative to your page, for example: where would that even go? Point to the location of your assets that your server exposes _as URL_.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `index.html` ensure the links start with `/` which will also serve them from the `public` directory like so:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>    
    <title>Planner</title>
    <script src="/codebase/library.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <link href="/codebase/library.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
    <link href="/styles.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Note** you will also need a `/public/codebase/` directory to serve `library.js` and `library.css` by the looks of things too.